# ¿Cómo ordenar una lista de archivos en forma numérica?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código que utilizo para leer los archivos de un directorio:

```
path = 'path'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if 
             isfile(join(path, f))]
```

Pero dentro de mi directorio tengo archivos del 1 al 30, he utilizado la función `sorted` pero siempre me regresa como `['archivo1.txt', 'archivo10.txt', 'archivo2.txt']`.

¿Cómo puedo ordenarlos de forma natural para que tome a los números como tales, y el `2` esté antes que el `10`?

Comment: Sinceramente, no entiendo lo que quieres lograr con tu programa. ¿Lo que quieres ahorita es que todos tus archivos vayan en orden `archivo1.txt, archivo2.txt, archivo3.txt`...?

Comment: @RolinAzmitia Si es lo que quería hacer, una disculpa por la tardanza.

Answer (score 4):

Una forma de resolver esto seria que **usaras tu propio método de sort**, en este caso dices que todos tus archivos se llaman **archivoXX.txt**, tendríamos que usar el `.` como separador, lo cual nos genera un sub lista de un largo de 2 que es `[archivoXX]` y `[txt]` entonces ahora decimos que transforme los últimos dígitos a partir de la ultima letra `o` de `[archivoXX]` en enteros lo que nos deja solamente con `XX`, y en base a estos que haga el sort.

Quedaría así:

```
onlyfiles = sorted(onlyfiles, key=lambda s: int(s.split('.')[0][7:]))
```

puedes encontrar mas información en --> http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: No veo cómo el código que has puesto hace lo que describes en la respuesta. Creo que lo de "a partir de la última `o `" no está implementado.

Comment: @JLDiaz Una disculpa, olvide modificar el código, ya que puse con el que estaba haciendo pruebas. Con referencia a lo de "a partir de la ultima o" es donde hago que se analice el string a partir de la posición 7 hacia adelante `[7:]` ya que la posición 6 es la letra 'o' .

Answer (score 3):

Lo que ocurre es que en tu caso el `sort` se hace de forma alfabética y claramente el `2` es posterior al `1` por lo que el orden siempre será `archivo1.txt`, `archivo11.txt` y por último `archivo2.txt` para darte un ejemplo.

Lo que se puede hacer, básicamente es lo mismo que ya te propuso @J.Gama, pero me parece un poco más flexible. La idea es usar las expresiones regulares para extraer solo los números de cada archivo, convertirlos a un entero y ordenar por dicho valor:

```
import  re

lista = ['archivo1.txt', 'archivo10.txt', 'archivo2.txt']

r = re.compile(r"(\d+)")  
lista.sort(key=lambda x: int(r.search(x).group(1)))
print(lista)

['archivo1.txt', 'archivo2.txt', 'archivo10.txt']
```

Algunos comentarios:

- `sort()` es un método de toda lista, el ordenamiento es "inline", es decir no retorna una nueva lista sino que ordena la actual
- Usamos el parámetro `key` que nos permite definir una función anónima (`lambda`) que tiene la lógica que te comentaba más arriba. Internamente `sort` invocará en todo momento está función para obtener el dato que usará para ordenar.
- Esta solución no te obliga a que la parte de los números tenga siempre la misma longitud, es decir `01`, `02`,  etc, como pareciera que son tus archivos.
- @Mariano me hizo notar algo: para el ejemplo, simplemente usando el patrón `(\d+)` alcanza, lo que hace esto es "extraer" los grupos de caracteres numéricos, en este caso tienes uno solo que es el número: achivo**12**.txt. El patrón `"\D+(\d+)\D+"` es más restrictivo y serviría solo si además queremos validar el formato ya que verifica `\D+`: cualquier caracter no numérico, `(\d+)`: los caracteres del número y por último, otro conjunto de caracteres no numéricos `\D+`, en este caso si no coincide el formato (aunque tengamos un conjunto de números) no obtendríamos valor alguno y tendríamos una Excepción. Y al mismo precio me hizo acordar de anteponer el identificador de cadena de expresión regular: `r"(\d+)"` ya que así evitamos tener que "escapar" la `\`.

Comment: @Mariano, es totalmente cierto, lo que pasa es que tengo la manía de validar el formato completo, lo cual es inútil en este código por que tampoco lo estamos controlando.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno he intentado algo muy tonto pero funciona, en mi caso como todos los archivos tenían el mismo nombre después con un `for` itere sobre la longitud de dicha lista y fui sustituyendo el número y de esa manera me lo dio ordenada.

```
for i in range(1, len(listFiles)):
    auxList.append(path + 'archivo'+str(i)+'.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo he creado mi primer "programa" en Python para listar mp3:

- 1 Abre una ventana del sistema para escoger directorio.
- 2 Ordena alfabéticamente todos los archivos terminados en .mp3
- 3 Añade un numeral y espacio al principio de cada archivo de la lista
  con 5 dígitos.
- 4 Imprime en archivo .txt de nombre preestablecido y guarda en el
  mismo directorio.
- 5 Cierra el programa.

Bueno, pues resulta que sort no ordena igual que windows. "10CC" aparece antes que "4 Non Blondes" porque 1 es menor que 4, pero en Windows aparece al revés, porque 4 es menor que 10 y probablemente distintos reproductores usen el método del sistema y otros uno como el de mi programa, por lo que no me sirve el índice a menos que cambie el nombre del archivo añadiendo esos dígitos, cosa que no quiero hacer. Puedo hacer que coincida con el sistema, pero hay reproductores en que no coincidirá. Sé que es absurdo, pero cualquiera podría programar si los lenguajes de programación no estuviesen desarrollados por programadores, que tienen una clara discapacidad sintáctico-gramatical. Puede verse incluso aquí en alguna respuesta o en esta misma ventana, que no puedes usar un retorno de carro sin recurrir al formateo.

Comment: Puedes definir tu propia función "key" de ordenación, Para resolver tu caso sería esta (en el comentario no se puede formatear correctamente, sorry):  `def mi_orden(x):   num, resto = re.match(r"^(\d*)(.*)", x).groups();   if not num: num="inf" ; return float(num), resto` Luego la usarías así `sorted(tu_lista_de_nombres, key=mi_orden)`